# How do I combine multiple queries in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, coffeescript, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to retrieve records that match two queries.

First one is match_phrase

```
"match_phrase": {
                    "searchstring": {
                    "query": "' . $searchQ . '",
                    "slop":  10
                    }
                }
```

Second one I am using multi match

```
"multi_match": {
                    "query":    "' . $searchQ . '",
                    "fields" : ["_all"],
                    "type":       "cross_fields",
                }
```

how can I do this correctly. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`bool/must`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) (or `bool/should`) query in order to combine your two queries:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "searchstring": {
              "query": "xyz",
              "slop": 10
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "xyz",
            "fields": [
              "_all"
            ],
            "type": "cross_fields"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Val , 
Many thanks for the tip in the right direction